# Asp.net 5 Vnext and Mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing in asp.net 5 vnext and I need to host it on linux ubuntu. I need to use mysql and entity framework. Can any body tell me how can I use asp.net vnext and entity framework with mysql?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: There isn't mysql connector implementation for ef7 yet

Comment: can I use another version of entity framework which has a mysql connector implementation such as entity framework 6?

Comment: Yes, but not for core

Comment: You can use EF6 as long as you don't use the Identity packages because they require EF7

Answer (score 0):

EFCore with ASP.NET and MySQL is now implemented. You have a choice of 3 different providers, the official one is still in preview.

https://damienbod.com/2016/08/26/asp-net-core-1-0-with-mysql-and-entity-framework-core/

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/index.html